# flask - data creation

Tags: python, flask

I'm following this tutorial.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vi-profile-page-and-avatars

I'm in the part 6 but I made a mistake and deleted the database.

I went back to part 4

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

I've recreated the database with the script `db_create.py` and migrated it.

However, I'm trying to add a few lines of data. I did this

```
from app import db, models
```

The line above is ok

But I'm adding this line `u = models.User(nickname='john', email='john@email.com')` and suddenly , I've got errors (see the trace below).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 324, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 725, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 158, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 260, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2702, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2598, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1696, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 144, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1550, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1606, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 725, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1523, in mapper
    argument = self.argument()
  File "/home/andy.kwok/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 283, in __call__
    (self.prop.parent, self.arg, n.args[0], self.cls)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|user, expression 'Post' failed to locate a name ("name 'Post' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Why?

Help, I'm pulling my hair off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because when `User` is being loaded, it's trying to look for `Post` which isn't loaded yet.

What you could try is to look for `__tablename__` in `Post` model. Now in `User` model where you have `relationship` to `Post` defined, use the string in `Post`'s `__tablename__`. That should work.

Comment: Hi @adarsh, you nailed it right. It was this line in `models.py` that was causing problem : `posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
`. Once I commented the line, things were fine.